# Regex to match pipe seperated strings inside brackets after dot

Tags: regex

I've been trying to write a regex and failed.

Here are some test cases illustrating what I'm trying to achieve:

| Name | Input | Match 1 | Match 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| No matches | `lorem ipsus` | - | - |
| Matches without pipes | `lorem {{ . }} ipsus` | `{{ . }}` | - |
| Matches with single pipe | `lorem {{ . | firstPipe }} ipsus` | `{{ . | firstPipe }}` | `firstPipe` |
| Matches with double pipes | `lorem {{ . | firstPipe | secondPipe }} ipsus` | `{{ . | firstPipe | secondPipe }}` | `firstPipe | secondPipe` |
| Matches whitespace tolerant | `lorem {{ .| firstPipe |secondPipe }} ipsus` | `{{ .| firstPipe |secondPipe }}` | `firstPipe |secondPipe` |
| Matches whitespace tolerant | `lorem {{ .|firstPipe| secondPipe}} ipsus` | `{{ . | firstPipe | secondPipe }}` | `firstPipe| secondPipe` |

What I'm looking for should be non-sensitive to whitespaces. It means that even though whitespace is missing before/after pipe character, brackets or dot it should still match.

**Match 1**: Matches everything that's inside brackets with optional whitespaces and has dot. Something like `{{\s*.\s*}}`,

**Match 2**: This one is optional. Here's what I can't get working. I would accept a behavior that returns pipe separated strings or alternatively a match for each named pipe before the bracket ends.

Comment: What about [`({{\s*\.\s*(?:\|\s*([^{}]*?)\s*)?}})`](https://regex101.com/r/gNGYhe/1)

Comment: Thank you for very fast response. I'm so happy to receive a solution directly, but now sadder to spend so many hours on this :) I'd accept your answer if you post it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```py
{{[^{}|]*(?:\|\s*((?:(?!{{).)*?)\s*)?}}
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/J1CS19/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^{}|]*                  any character except: '{', '}', '|' (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \|                       '|'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                               times (matching the least amount
                               possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          {{                       '{{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )*?                      end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }}                       '}}'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works as expected, really appreciated except it also catches `{{ lorem . | ipsus }}` but I'd like to only allow whitespace before dot so only ` {{ . | ipsus }}`. Sorry for not being clear on this. If it's a small change I'll accept your answer directly.

Comment: @U.Bulle `{{\s*\.\s*(?:\|\s*((?:(?!{{).)*?)\s*)?}}` - [see proof](https://regex101.com/r/J1CS19/2).